# Heroku: How does the postgreSQL Pricing work & how to limit it?

Tags: heroku

I've a site that is hosted in Heroku. It is an Ecommerce site that uploads user's designs (JPG, PNG, PSD files or AI files, PDFs, etc) but this are stored in Amazon and not heroku.

Right now I'm trying to get my costs down, so I'm checking the resources and I see this:

[image]

As you can see I've a Heroku Postgress Addon `Standard 0` that costs $50 monthly.

**I'm trying to bring the Heroku Postgress Addon cost down.**

> According to this [Heroku Page](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql), there are Postgres Plans at $9.
>
> However it has a Row Limit and offers no Storage Capacity.
>
> How this could affect my app?

**How do I change to this plan?**

```
heroku pg:info

=== DATABASE_URL, HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GOLD_URL
Plan:                  Standard 0
Status:                Available
Data Size:             18.3 MB
Tables:                26
PG Version:            10.7
Connections:           8/120
Connection Pooling:    Available
Credentials:           1
Fork/Follow:           Available
Rollback:              earliest from 2019-04-30 19:23 UTC
Created:               2019-03-05 16:08 UTC
Region:                us
Data Encryption:       In Use
Continuous Protection: On
Maintenance:           not required
Maintenance window:    Fridays 18:30 to 22:30 UTC
Add-on:                postgresql-polished-46417

=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BROWN_URL
Plan:                  Hobby-dev
Status:                Available
Connections:           0/20
PG Version:            10.6
Created:               2019-02-14 17:19 UTC
Data Size:             7.6 MB
Tables:                0
Rows:                  0/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow:           Unsupported
Rollback:              Unsupported
Continuous Protection: Off
Add-on:                postgresql-opaque-83191
```

Billing:

In my Billing acount I'm seeing that for march and april I'm beeing charged more than $50 USD.

**How can I limit this, to lets say $20 USD monthly?**
** We're only expecting 100 visits top!**

[image: &]

However, according to this [medium post](https://medium.com/@AndreyAzimov/how-free-heroku-really-works-and-how-to-get-maximum-from-it-daa53f2b3c57) visits is not a metric for which we're beeing charged. I just mentioned the 100 visits top as a reference.

Comment: The Hobby Basic plan is $9. I haven't tried it, but maybe that works?

Comment: How do I change to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free plan limits to 10k rows, correct, and once you've reached that limit, your inserts will start to fail. Been there.

It's really just as it's written. 10k rows, no storage limits. You could have a text column with a huge json or file in there and it wouldn't matter in storage, as long as it is under the row count limit.

You would be affected only when having to upgrade it to a bigger plan, say the 9$ which would give you 1M rows, as it's not an upgrade of your database but a migration to a new database, which you'd have to perform.

So in order to migrate you would have to put your app in maintenance mode, add the 9$ database, make it 'follow' your free database, wait a couple minutes as the 9$ database updates itself with the free database data, then make the 9$ database stop following the free database and lastly switch your app to the new 9$ database.

This last step, if you're using the DATABASE_URL environment variable is transparent for the app. Just detach the free database and attach the 9$ database,  take your app out of maintenance mode and you're done.

If you can have an hour or two of downtime, it's worth the savings. You can script this migration as it only uses heroku commands.

Another easy way to have a free and reliable database is to use AWS. Since heroku is inside AWS you just have to setup an RDS in the same region as your app is and switch the connection. Then you would have a free 30gb database for a year.

Comment: Answer: **It's really just as it's written. 10k rows, no storage limits. You could have a text column with a huge json or file in there and it wouldn't matter in storage**.